# Clicking on notification doesn't open mentioned activity

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am trying to open an `Activity` when the notification is clicked and below is my code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), NotificationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("msgBody",messageBody);
intent.putExtra(Constants.NOTIF_INTENT_TYPE,Constants.NOTIF_INTENT_TYPE);

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //Tried with many options here

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent,
                                         PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.otp_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Push MSG")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

**Android Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.com.pushapp">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".AndroidPushApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".PushSplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainApplicationScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Whenever I get notification from FCM I am calling this notification. The **NotificationActivity** is not opening whenever I click on notification, rather the app is opening(`splash screen->starting activity` of my usual app flow). Whenever I get notification while the app is already open, the `NotificationActivity` is getting opened, but not when app is not already opened. Could someone please help me on resolving this?

**Note:** Please I am reiterating that `NotificationActivity.class` is not getting opened when clicked on notification when app is not already opened state.

Comment: Use FLAG_ONE_SHOT https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT and let me know.

Comment: @SagarGangawane Tried no luck

Comment: @rick Post your _AndroidManifest.xml_ please.

Comment: @earthw0rmjim Please check now

Answer (score 31):

According to `FCM` Documentation, for receiving and handling messages,

> If you want to receive notifications when your app is in the
>   foreground, you need to add some message handling logic.
>
> To receive messages, use a service that extends
>   FirebaseMessagingService. Your service should override the
>   onMessageReceived callback, which is provided for most message types,
>   with the following exceptions:
>
> 1). Notifications delivered when your app is in the background. In
>   this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray.
>   A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
>
> 2). Messages with both notification and data payload, both background
>   and foreground. In this case, the notification is delivered to the
>   device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras
>   of the intent of your launcher Activity.

[image]

So Basically, we have two types of Payloads

**1).** Notification Payload

**2).** Data Payload

**3).** Both (an additional type we can consider).

Now let's discuss one by one these payloads. Before that you need to understand how can you send these Payloads to your app. All you have to do is to make use of any tool that can perform `HTTP POST Request`. In my case, I am using the **Postman** tool, a Google Chrome Plugin.

Before making a `HTTP Post Request` for `FCM`, you have to consider three things:

**1). HTTP Post Request URL :** https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

**2). Request Headers :**

i). Content-Type : application/json

ii). Authorization : key = YOUR_SERVER_KEY

Below is the screenshot for the same to show how it looks.

[image]

**3). Body :** In this we are going to have `JSON` for `Notification` and `Data Payloads`.

- So starting with **Notification Payload**, the simplest of all. In this case,  `onMessageReceived()` is called only when the app is in `Foreground`, For all other cases, it's a `System Tray Notification`, which opens the `Launcher Activity` when clicked. This is helpful when you don't want to control `Notifications` by your own and not much data to deal with when `Notification` comes. You can even control the sound, icon and click_action(only when the app is in `Foreground`) without writing any code in your `onMessageReceived()`. One example of a body of such `HTTP POST Request` is attached in the screenshot below.

[image]

For opening desired `Activity` when sending click_action parameter, you have to use the below code in your `onMessageReceived()`.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (null != remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction()) {
            startActivity(remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction(), null, this);
    }
}
```

and below is your `startActivity()` method :

```
public void startActivity(String className, Bundle extras, Context context) {
    Class cls = null;
    try {
        cls = Class.forName(className);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        //means you made a wrong input in firebase console
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, cls);
    if (null != extras) {
        intent.putExtras(extras);
    }
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

> NOTE : This `click_action` key will work only when the app is in
>   Foreground, for all other case when the app is in Background and
>   closed, it doesn't work. It doesn't  even open the Launcher Activity,
>   in case of Background and Closed, if this parameter is specified.

- Now comes the **Data Payload**. This is similar to the one we have in `GCM`. This is very important if we want to handle all the `Notification` stuff by ourselve same as we all were doing in case of `GCM`. Example of a body of such `HTTP POST Request` is shown below.

[image]

So in this case, `onMessageReceived()` is called everytime and this will work in the same way as that of `GCM`, so helpful to all of us. You have to `Override` `onMessageReceived()` as shown below.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
    if (null != data && 0 < data.size()) {
        if (data.containsKey("custom_key_1")) {
            sendNotification(data.get("custom_key_1"));
        }
    }
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DesiredActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

- Last but not the least, we can send both `Notification` and `Data Payloads` as well. In this case, `onMessageReceived()` is called when the app is in `Foreground`. For background and closed state, `Notification` comes in the system tray similar to `Notification Payload` but the only difference is we can have `data extras` as well that we can use to redirect user to a desired `Activity`, when clicked on a `Notification`. Below is the example of a body of such `HTTP POST Request`.Example of a body of such `HTTP POST Request` is shown below.

[image]

When clicking on a `Notification` on System Tray, it will open the `Launcher Activity` and You need to `Override` `onCreate()` of your `Launcher Activity` to get the `data extras` and redirect user to the desired `Activity`. Below is the code, you have to write in `onCreate()` of your `Activity` to redirect user to the desired `Activity`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("custom_key_1") && getIntent().getStringExtra("custom_key_1")
            .equals("custom_value_1")){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, DesiredActivity.class));
        finish();
        return;
    }

    // other operations
}
```

Another case to this type is, when your `Launcher Activity` is defined as `launchMode="true"` in the `manifest` and when the `Notification` Arrives, your `Launcher Activity` is in the `Foreground`. So when you click on the Notification, you have to `Override` the `onNewIntent()` method in your `Launcher Activity` to open the desired `Activity`. Below is the sample code for the same.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("custom_key_1") && getIntent().getStringExtra("custom_key_1")
                .equals("custom_value_1")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, DesiredActivity.class));
            finish();
    }
}
```

So in short, I would say it's good to go with the **Data Payload** type as it provides more flexibility and control over the `Notification` and more importantly as we all are used to `GCM`, so this type is what we all would like to prefer.

> Note : Some devices are having issue receiving Notifications in
>   Background as I found some queries over same here. Moreover at the
>   time, I was investigating these cases, my ASUS phone was not receiving
>   notifications in Background for any of the types mentioned above. So
>   not sure what's the issue with these devices.

Comment: As mentioned I need to open activity on the click of notification, not in onmessagereceived, please suggest

Comment: The solution handle each case for the same. Please go through it one more time and let me know where you are not getting

Comment: Please have a look at the updated answer, hopefully this will help :)

Comment: nice info. it will help other to save time :)

Comment: regarding the `fcm.googleapis.com` console, is it possible to distinguish between iOS and Android devices? Right now the iOS developers want to send `click_action` to suit their purpose, however, this breaks the Android app because when the app is in the background, clicking the notification has no effect - it doesn't even launch the app.

Comment: Thanks @MukeshRana very helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in my app

This link helped me: 
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation

What you need to do is define parent activity for your desired activity in Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<!-- MainActivity is the parent for ResultActivity -->
<activity
    android:name=".ResultActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
```

And then use TaskStackBuilder in onMessageReceived method to create pending intent

```
// Create an Intent for the activity you want to start
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
// Create the TaskStackBuilder and add the intent, which inflates the back stack
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
// Get the PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
// then use this pending intent to build your notification
```

Comment: thanks man, it worked. I was missing `stackBuilder.getPendingIntent()` this part.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in pendingIntent.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationId /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and also pass the same id to `notificationManager`

```
 notificationManager.notify(notificationId /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any `Activity` to be receiver for push notifications:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.MESSAGE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This intent filter for the activity specifies which activity will be launched in response to push notification (`PACKAGE_NAME` is your Android app package)

So you can add this intent filter in your `Activity` which you want to open on the click of Push notification.

Comment: Why a down vote? It has worked for me. Also try adding this line..      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

Comment: this answer should be more clearer and specific written code

Answer (score 0):

If you read the firebase docs in detail, there are two types of payloads

- **Data payload**
- **Notification payload**

The data payload triggers the **onMessageReceived()** callback when app is both foreground and background. This is not the case with notification payload, which triggers the callback in only foreground state. So, if you use the data payload this problem should be solved.

Comment: Notification is getting fired in my case everytime. I have a problem with opening a screen, not with notification firing

Comment: Try using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  flag in the intent and FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag in the PendingIntent.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code and let me know.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats the intented behaviour. If your app is in background, notification is created by android system which does not have your pendingIntent action.So it does not work. In the foreground case it works because notification is created by your code.

Please check the doc in the below link.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device#receive_and_handle_messages

Comment: Then how can I manage to open the intended activity by clicking on notification irrespective of whether the app is in foreground or background. Right now my app is getting opened on clicking on notification when it is in background. Please suggest

Comment: when server sends a notification payload to device via gcm or fcm, you have to add data payload i.e., "data":{"your_action_key":"action_value_like_activity"} and read from your _onMessageRecievedmethod(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)_ and create notification by parsing remoteMessage.getData().

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not to add a comment as I'm a fairly new comer.

You can just do the following two things for further investigating:

1. After the notification has been created, use shell command "adb shell dumpsys activity i [your package name]" to see your notification in detail, to confirm it is really what you want.
   **Remember to replace "[your package name]" with your own package name;**
2. Tracking the event log during the time you are reproducing this using "adb logcat -v threadtime -b events".

Post both of these and we might get something useful about what is going wrong under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Set your pending intent like below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), NotificationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("msgBody",messageBody);
intent.putExtra(Constants.NOTIF_INTENT_TYPE,Constants.NOTIF_INTENT_TYPE);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

add it to your notification using

```
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my FirebaseMessagingService:

```
/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody, String data) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(id++ /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```