# Can we push only data message from Firebase Notification console

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have implemented FCM successfully in my project.

Is it possible to push **only** data message from Firebase console.

Comment: Nope, you can't AFAIK. You need to make use of any HTTP Post Request tool to send data payload to devices. For more information regarding how to do that, you can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40417127/clicking-on-notification-doesnt-open-mentioned-activity/40458361#40458361

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, no. When sending messages through the Firebase Console, it will be treated as a notification payload and will be handled as such.

You can however, include custom key-value pairs in the *Advance Options* section in the console, this will be treated as a part of the data payload. But the message will be treated as having both Notification **and** Data payload.

If you insist on sending a **data only** payload, you should make use of the FCM REST API.

Comment: Any news on this topic? I couldn't find any. If it still doesn't work it's a tragic that google doesn't offer the option.

Comment: No updates yet.