# Which event is called when app is in background mode?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple), when the message is both a notification and data message and the app is in the background, the message is received as follows:

```
Notification: system tray
Data: in extras of the intent.
```

Which intent is it refering to?

From the Firebase Notification Console I sent a message with Custom data, ie with some Key/Value. Is this considered a combined Notification and Data message?  My onMessageReceived event does not fire when the app is in the background. Only the notification shows in the Notification bar at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Which intent is it refering to?*

The intent that starts the activity. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40185654/4625829).

> *From the Firebase Notification Console I sent a message with Custom data, ie with some Key/Value. Is this considered a combined Notification and Data message?*

Yes. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41161456/4625829).

Comment: Thanks. For the first question, does it mean that the app won't know about the message until it is launched to the foreground?

Comment: Yup. The intial message contained in the `notification` message will only be handled by the Android system tray, not your client app.